# How to send push notification from azure to windows mobile cordova app

Tags: windows, cordova, azure, push-notification

Hi i am using azure process to send the push notification to windows 10 
  above version hybrid app and i use the below code to send the notification

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-
  mobile-cordova-get-started-push

i got this document there 
  pushRegistration.on('registration', function (data) { 
  this method is not firing is there any process to register before to send 
  notification

Answer (score 1):

You have to implement a registerForPushNotifications method an call it every time user opens the App:

```
var pushRegistration = null;
 function registerForPushNotifications() {
   pushRegistration = PushNotification.init({
       android: { senderID: 'Your_Project_ID' },
       ios: { alert: 'true', badge: 'true', sound: 'true' },
       wns: {}
   });
```

If pushRegistration.on is not called, maybe registration is not complete or there is some error. 
Create a breakpoint or print some message in:

```
pushRegistration.on('error', handleError);
```

And take a look if it's something wrong.

Also, you can check if there is some missing configuration following the Notification Hubs Diagnosis guidelines: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/notification-hubs/notification-hubs-push-notification-fixer

Comment: How to registration the push notification

Comment: You have to implement a registerForPushNotifications method and the device will be able to receive notification (answer edited)

Comment: I added that method now it is firing there is no rights for azure account so it is not firing after executed this method i did not got any notification

Comment: Is it firing or not? Sorry but I don't understand: "there is no rights for azure account so it is not firing after executed this method" If the method is firing but you are not receiving notifications, this is another question. I can recommend: Open Visual Studio > Server Explorer > Notification Hubs and check in devices registrations if your device is on the list (Check Notification Hubs Diagnosis guidelines in the answer). If you are running a simulator you are not going to receive notifications. You have to run your App on a real device.